# Can OpenGL be run not fullscreen (contained in window or layout instead) in Android?

Tags: android, layout, opengl-es, window

This might be an odd question. I'm basically wondering if there's a way to use OpenGL content, but not have it take up the entire screen.  My desire is to use OpenGL to render some objects, and below that have working buttons that determine what will happen to said objects.

Comment: Yes offcourse you can do it, name your platform, gui framework please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a GLSurfaceViewActivity, create a normal Activity and embed a [GLSurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) into a ViewGroup where you need it.  There is probably some other glue you'll find you need that GLSurfaceViewActivity generates automatically.

However, note, that due to the vastly different rendering mechanisms between Surfaces and other Views, you may find some unexpected rendering issues.  The SurfaceView will effectively be a "window" through which the OpenGL will be revealed, and other normal views may be allowed to draw above that window.  Also, its a good idea to make sure the GLSurfaceView is the only SurfaceView in the hierarchy.

Comment: Appreciate the insight. It will be the only surface view. I basically need a way to render animations consistently while having working text views and buttons.  Just trying a bunch of options to see what works best because I read that the built in drawing mechanisms were less effective. (My animation is a guage or speed dial as an example).

Comment: Sounds like your needs are simple enough that you should be able to get sufficient performance out of a Handler.postDelayed(..) redraw loop, but only you can tell for sure.